# C# LINQ convert IEnumerable<IGrouping> to IEnumerable<IEnumerable> elegantly?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, igrouping

If you have an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, T>>`, say from

```
var ans = src.GroupBy(s => s.Field);
```

Is there a better way (rarely used LINQ method/variation) to convert to an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` then nested `Select`s like so:

```
var ans2 = ans.Select(g => g.Select(s => s));
```

For those that aren't understanding,

```
var anst = ans2.Select(g => g.GetType().ReflectedType).All(t => t == typeof(Enumerable));
```

should return `anst == true`.

Comment: What interface is `IGrouping<T>`?  I only know of `IGrouping<K, T>`, which is already `IEnumerable<T>`.  And since `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, T>>` is already automatically an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`  What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Your test doesn't match your question... In `IEnumerable<IEnumerable> ans2 = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<int>(),1);` ans2 is of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>` but your test would return `anst` = false. This is because the only type for which `t == typeof(Enumerable)` would return true is `Enumerable` (not the interface, the actual class Enumerable). This is almost certainly *not* what you are intending.

Comment: Is this perhaps an A/B problem? What are you trying to do that you feel you need to do this conversion? As others have said you already have something that implements `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>`. Are you actually having a different problem for which you think the above is the solution?

Comment: You have a very strange requirement, so I will not put this in my answer, but looking at the reference source, if you can modify your call to GroupBy this will pass your test: src.GroupBy(s => s.Field), (key, items) => items.Skip(0));

Comment: If you meant to convert GroupEnumerable to Enumerable, you already have the slickest way possible. No need to look anywhere else. Unless you have a problem with that nested select.

Comment: @Jason `Skip(0)` is a very neat way to accomplish the same thing. Nice.

Comment: @Chris A bit late ;) but your `ans2` is not of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` but rather `IEnumerable<List<int>>` which would show up when doing something like `Skip()` on the groups which would optimize for `List` since that is the actual type. Note that the use of `ReflectedType` on the returned type causes `Enumerable` to be returned for most LINQ operator classes.

Comment: @Jason If you modify you answer to use `Skip(0)` I will accept it, as that has come closest to simplifying - especially since there are some optimizations for `0` in the .Net Core `Skip` method. Since `Enumerable.Select` takes a `Func` there is no optimization possible for `Select(x => x)` though perhaps there should be.

Comment: It was a long time ago but I think my point was that `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> ans2 = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<int>(),1);` is a perfectly valid line of code. So while the actual type is `IEnumerable<List<int>>` it is actually also a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` so your test for whether something is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` is disagreeing with the c' compiler on whether something matches that type. Your anst check is a much more strict check of the input and it made no sense to me as to why you *needed* the reflected Types to all be Enumerable.

Comment: ie what exactly was the problem that required your input to match that anst check and to reject something that could be assigned to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. It feels like perhaps the fix was not to hack your input around with things like `.Skip(0)` but to fix whatever the real problem was that left you wanting to do this. I would imagine that whatever that real problem was though is a long time in the past now though...

Comment: @Chris one purpose is to bypass LINQ optimizations in methods like `Take` and `Skip` for specific types such as `IList<T>` or `T[]`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to avoid the nested select is using the `AsEnumerable()` method.

```
var ans = src.GroupBy(s => s.Field).Select(e => e.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Turns out `IGrouping<T>.AsEnumerable()` returns `IGrouping<T>`. Who knew?

Comment: @NetMage yup, `IGrouping<T>.AsEnumerable()` returns `IGrouping<T>` but it does the job of having the result set be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` without a "nested select" as your question suggests.

Comment: But that `Select` is literally doing nothing. Leaving it off would get the same result because `IGrouping<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, `IGrouping<T>` **is** an `IEnumerable<T>` because it Implements `IEnumerable<T>`. what exactly are you trying to accomplish then? if having an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` as you've initially asked doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: I added a test in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case IGrouping already implements that interface:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new[] {
            new MyClass { a = "1", b = "2"},
            new MyClass { a = "1", b = "3"},
            new MyClass { a = "2", b = "4"},
            new MyClass { a = "2", b = "5"} };

        var ans = foo.GroupBy(x => x.a);

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>> ans2 = ans;
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>> result = ans2.ToArray();
    }

    private class MyClass
    {
        public string a;
        public string b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting result to an array ?

Comment: Turns out `IGrouping<T>.Cast<IEnumerable<T>>()` returns `IGrouping<T>`.

Comment: ToArray will force an enumeration of the IEnumerable so I will see an exception thrown if something went wrong. Before that line, none of the grouping or casting code would actually do any work.

Comment: NetMage, Cast<T> returns IEnumerable<T> - the T objects may also happen to implement IGrouping<T>, but that's not relevant here. Instead of var ans2 above, you can write IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>> ans2 and it works fine. I edited my answer to remove the var to make this more clear.

Comment: You will see that if you remove the `Cast` from the assigment to `ans2`, the code still compiles and works. The `Cast` _does nothing_.

Comment: @NetMage: Exactly. An `IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, T>>` is *already* an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`.  The conversion you want is *built in to the language*, so it is very unclear what you are asking for. You've already got it.

Comment: I had added the Cast<> for clarity before when using 'var' for ans2 but the explicit types instead of var show it even more clearly - so removed Cast<>.

Comment: @EricLippert There may be no technical reason (make `Key` inaccessible?, make Reflection expecting `Enumerable` work? - whie minimizing overhead) - it mainly changes the way the LINQPad `Dump` method displays the results.

Comment: @EricLippert I have since come up with another reason - to change the way LINQ extension methods optimize when applied to the groups. They use `GetType` to determine the runtime object and optimize on that.